# Save Django query to use multiple times

Tags: python, django

How can I save Django query in variable to use it multiple times? for example
define save a query in variable names `query1` and use it in where I want.

```
query1 = objects.filter(name__startswith='a').filter(name__endswith='z') 
q1 = Blog.objects.filter(query1)
q2 = Post.objects.filter(query1)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```py
from django.db import models


my_filter = models.Q(names__startswith='a') & models.Q(name__startswith='z')

Post.objects.filter(my_filter)
Blog.objects.filter(my_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

From the docs:

> A Q object (django.db.models.Q) is an object used to encapsulate a collection of keyword arguments. These keyword arguments are specified as in “Field lookups” above.

I will add an example when I’m at my computer.

Comment: It would be better if you could provide an example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible save filters in dictionary and use them later so in example:

```
filters = {
    "name__startswith":"a",
    "name__endswith":"z",
}
q1 = Blog.objects.filter(**filters)
q2 = Post.objects.filter(**filters)
```